# initializationListener is null, you will not receive any callbacks - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, callback

What kind of error is this? I've looked for a fix but haven't found anything related

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk6uY.png

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/iunityadslistener-is-not-getting-callbacks.794514/

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same error.

You need to add the `InuityAdsInitializationListener` class and the `OnInitializationComplete` and `OnInitializationFailed` methods.
The error is occurring because of the absence of those.

Please refer here for more information.
https://docs.unity.com/ads/InitializingTheUnitySDK.html

Answer (score 0):

You need two things. As said above, you need to implement the `IUnityAdsInitializationListener` interface as well as it's methods.

However, you also need to tell the Advertisement which class implements that interface inside of your `Advertisement.Initailize` function. If you are upgrading from an old version, you may not notice the new overloaded functions.
Specifically you need to call

```
Advertisement.Initialize(gameId, testMode, IUnityAdsInitializationListener);
```

For example:

```
Advertisement.Initialize(gameId, false, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the Following
For Initilization
Advertisement.Initialize(unityAdsId, true, this);

For Loading
Advertisement.Load(intrPlacementId, this);

For Showing Ads
Advertisement.Show(rewardedPlacementId, this);

So the thing is that you have to add "this" key word in inilization and loading and showing methods

I have solved my issue using above code